# How to calculate sin in gradian using java

Tags: java, trigonometry

To calculate `sin` in `radians` and `degrees` we can use the below methods, but i couldn't find a way to calculate `sin` in `grad`.

```
Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(x));
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `x` is expressed in radians: `Math.sin(x)`
If `x` is expressed in degrees: `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x))`
If `x` is expressed in grads: `Math.sin(Math.PI * x / 200)`

Comment: Shouldn't `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))` give the same result as `Math.sin(200 * 100 / Math.PI)` then? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+90+degrees+to+grads

Comment: No. `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))` equals `Math.sin(Math.PI / 2)`. Right?

Comment: Right, but that's not what I am asking about. Do you agree with me that 90 degrees is the same as 100 grads? Then according to your answer, `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))` should give the same result as `Math.sin(200 * 100 / Math.PI)`. But it doesn't.

Comment: Right, Zabri. Now I see what you mean. I corrected my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: calculating inverse of tan in grads using Math.sin(Math.PI * x / 200) gives incorrect results....

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is expressed as [gradian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian), you can easily convert it to degree as one grad is `9 / 10` of a degree.

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(9.0 / 10 * x));
```

Comment: Should be `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(9.0 / 10 * x));`

Answer (score -3):

the way i would do this would be to go back to basic Calculus.

```
if:  f(x) = sin x

    f'(x) = cos x
```

The gradient function for sin x is cos x

so the gradient is:

```
Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(x));
```

This being the function